# CRM 2011: To display the webpage again the web browser needs to resend the information error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have to change statecode on the form and get instantly response. I did succesfully, but I have a problem. If I need to get instantly response from form, I need to write

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

But when I trigger the code repeatly, I got an error

```
To Display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've previously submitted.
```

I used

```
location.href = location.href
```

But form did not postback so I did not get instantly response. 
I need to solve it in Javascript. How can I solve it?

Comment: I think updating status from plugin is more cleaner than updating from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving the form, data is sent to save. On refresh the error occurs because data will be send again to save. It can update information again which might have been changed by other process. It is dangerous because it can overwrite the information. Internet Explorer is throwing this error just to prevent the problem.

To avoid the problem, I would recommend you to move the logic to a plugin if its possible.